# "Sorry, assemblyscript is not supported in your system, use --contract=rust " error in NEAR

Tags: smartcontracts, contract, near, assemblyscript

I just want to use create-near-app package from the npm registry as assemblyscript and react. But it gives [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx36I.png) error, how can i fix that ?

Comment: Well, let me think... did you sue `--contract=rust`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna i want to install with assemblyscript and react, when i don't write --contract option it's installed as rust

Comment: I don't know if it's a general problem or something specific to your architecture. You could open an issue on the `create-near-app` github repo